# tufte-style book url in marginnote

Tags: tufte, marginnote

How do I put a `\url{}` in a `\marginnote{}` without error using tufte-book document? I have already tried `\marginnote{\url{http}}` but I get the error illegal parameter number in definition of ...

Comment: The following: \documentclass{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
AAA
\marginnote{\url{http}}
\end{document}
 works OK (pdflatex, MikTeX). Additional information, in particular MWE, is needed.

Answer (score 3):

## Remarks

It seems to work fine, if you load the `url` package. You need to escape special symbols like `$`, `%` or `#` using a preceeding `\`, as in `\#`. See also th example.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149105/tufte-style-book-url-in-marginnote/149133\#149133}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: I think the OP has got some illegal characters like `#` in the *real* url...

Comment: No it doesn't. See how third line it overflows because of the dashes (-) if you keep on adding more dashes it won't wrap.

Comment: @user14492 `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`

Comment: Now I get option clash for `url`...

Comment: @user14492 `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}` before `\documentclass`

Answer (score 2):

It works partially when you make a citation of the style `\cite{some-citation}`. I found it much better to use the call to `\url{}` inside the bibliography document as opposed to the call. It wraps the long URL just fine in the margin notes.

Example:

```
@misc{codebook,
  title={What is a Codebook?},
  note={\url{https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/content/shared/ICPSR/faqs/what-is-a-codebook.html}},
  journal={ICPSR Find & Analyze Data},
  author={ICPSR},
  year={2019},
  month={March},
  day={30}
  }
```

and then cite the author with `\cite{codebook}`. This works just fine in my documents.